# One way binding mode, the other way around

Tags: aurelia

There are four binding modes in Aurelia as [documented](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/5):

- `.bind` - Uses the default binding. One-way binding for everything but
  form controls, which use two-way binding.
- `.one-way` - Flows data one
  direction: from the view-model to the view.
- `.two-way` - Flows data
  both ways: from view-model to view and from view to view-model.
- `.one-time` - Renders data once, but does not synchronize changes after
  the initial render.

I'm looking for a `.one-way` binding but the other way around, with the data flow from view to view-model. My use-case is dirty-bit where you want to know when the view is dirty.

Comment: Not a professional with this, but looking at the options - is there a way to do this using the `.two-way` binding mode?

Comment: You can but then you don't want the dirty bit to be set from the outside. It's something internal to the view.

Comment: https://github.com/aurelia/templating-binding/issues/33

Answer (score 0):

ValueConverters are bidirectional and could possibly be an OK workaround until it is implemented as described in the issue Jeremy linked to.

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-value-converters/1

Answer (score 0):

you can use `attribute.from-view="variable"` for a one way binding from view to viewmodel
https://github.com/aurelia/binding/pull/618